# Rails: has_one of a has_many association with criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an instance method that works that I would like to declare as a has_one relationship. How can I define a has_one through relationship from a has_many through?

This method works:

```
class Facility
  has_many :locations
  has_many :events, though: :locations

  def upcoming_event
    events.
      where('events.start_time >= ?', Time.zone.now).
      order('events.start_time ASC').
      first
  end
end
```

This relationship doesn't:

```
has_one :upcoming_event, -> {
  where('start_time >= ?', Time.zone.now).
  order('start_time ASC')
}, through: :locations, class_name: "Event"
```

Comment: Really not sure why you'd want to do this. Do you intend to assign events to the `upcoming_event` property? If not, there's no reason to prefer `has_one` over a simple accessor method. If it were me, I'd make an `upcoming` scope on your `Event` model to encapsulate the `where` and `order` clauses, and then simply call `my_facility.events.upcoming.first` and skip the entire `upcoming_event` property/`has_one` debate completely.

Comment: You don't need to `limit(1).first`, you can just call `.first`. The `limit(1)` will be discarded completely by the `.first` call, which overwrites whatever `limit` you may have previously specified.

Comment: @meagar thanks, I removed the `limit(1)`, I did not know that. I have developed a preference to declare relationships like this with the relationship macros, in part to make it easier to understand a model by grouping related functionality visually, which is what lead me here.

Answer (score 0):

Following Meagar's suggestion, there's an alternative that should accommodate your preference to group related functionality:

```
class Facility
  has_many :locations
  has_many :events, though: :locations do
    def upcoming
      where('start_time >= ?', Time.zone.now).order('start_time ASC')
    end
  end
end
```

This makes clear that upcoming is a method on the relationship, not on the Event model. It also allows you to write:

```
facility.events.upcoming
```

Which to me (and this is an opinion) communicates intent and hierarchy more clearly than `facility.upcoming_events`

Comment: It also breaks the law of demeter, which would cause me a lot of headache on this current project.